# The Occurrence Rate of Lunar/Solar Eclipses and Its Effect on a Planet

Tags: solar-eclipse, lunar-eclipse, earth-like-planet

I was pondering over ideas for fantasy worlds and came across one that begged a question about the effect of eclipses on the Earth. If a total lunar/solar eclipse happened every 80 years or so instead of the current frequency, what else might change about Earth? I tried searching around but didn't quite get an answer I wanted. We can assume convenient rotational axes or orbit habits to help answers, the scope is more about on the planet itself (not solar system-wise). Basically, considering realistic or reality-adjacent physics.

Specifically:

- 1.) Diurnal cycle of this planet (night and day cycle length)
- 2.) The Sun/Moon's relative size and distance from this planet
- 3.) Is the moon a satellite planet to this planet?
- 4.) Would tides be normal/faster/longer? Would the bodies of water be different?

Anything else you may add would be great too! I appreciate any help, and I hope you have a great one.

Comment: I think this question should be asked on [worldbuilding.se]  You have a desired effect and you want to build the science to justify the effect.  That's not an astronomy question.

Comment: Currently the question is unclear. Try to formulate in cause-effect relationships i.e. are you asking "what effects do solar eclipses have on planets, as the cause of something" or "what cause can lead to rare solar eclipses as effect, and what other possible effects would this have?"